# Save to Google Drive - Choose Location

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive-api

Can you print the current webpage in Chrome (as a PDF), and upload it to a specific location within Google Drive?

I'm looking for either addon or to achieve this programatically? Maybe using a html tag of some kind?

Comment: If you control the webpage, the Drive APIs might help you with saving files to Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has this ability built in - [Print a page in Chrome](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1379552)

Answer (score 0):

To print any web page, press Ctrl+P